# Trying to differentiate hyperboles and idioms

Tags: idioms, hyperbole

I'm having a hard time differentiating between hyperboles and idioms.

The sentence I have is calling someone a "dating app unicorn" because they know how to carry on a conversation. Would that be an idiom or a hyperbole?

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Danielle

Comment: Hyperbole is like the Super Bowl only bigger!

Comment: OED - **Hyperbole**: a. Rhetoric. A figure of speech - [an] exaggerated ... statement, used to express strong feeling or produce a strong impression, and not intended to be understood literally. e.g. *"I have told you **a million times** to look in a dictionary for the answer to such questions."* ++ **Idiom** A form of expression, ... specially. a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from the meanings of the individual words. e.g. *"People who don't look in dictionaries are **a sandwich short of a picnic***."

Comment: @Greybeard Another comedian.

Comment: You lost me at *dating app unicorn*. It might be an idiom because of the use of the word unicorn, but it's not an idiom I recognize. This would be hyperbolic: You are the best conversationalist of all time, and I mean EVER EVER EVER!!! I suppose calling someone a *unicorn* could be hyperbolic -- we've all heard talk of them but none of us has ever seen one. Unicorns are rare to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an idiom because an idiom is a standard usage.

It is hyperbole because it exaggerates the person's uniqueness and desirability.

It is also a metaphor because the person is not a legendary creature.

Comment: But note that "unicorn" is an idiom of sorts, even though it's only one word.

Comment: Thanks! And it looks like it's written just as "hyperbole" and not like I had written "a hyperbole" Is that right?